# Checking a list to see if file exist in powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-4.0

I have a list of files that I want to check a directory in powershell to see if they exist. I'm not too familiar with powershell but this is what I have so far that doesn't work.

```
$filePath = "C:\Desktop\test\"
$currentDate = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd

$listOfFiles = 
"{0}{1}testFile.txt",
"{0}{1}Base.txt",
"{0}{1}ErrorFile.txt",
"{0}{1}UploadError.txt"`
-f $filePath, $currentDate

foreach ( $item in $listOfFiles ) 
{ 
    [System.IO.File]::Exists($item)
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `Test-Path` cmdlet.

```
$filePath = "C:\Desktop\test\"
$currentDate = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
#I'm using 1..4 to create an array to loop over rather than manually creating each entry
#Also used String Interpolation rather than -f to inject the values
1..4 | ForEach-Object {Test-Path  "${filePath}${currentDate}file$_.txt"}
```

Edit:
    For the updated file names, here is how you could put them in an array to be looped through.

```
"testFile","Base","ErrorFile","UploadError" | ForEach-Object {
    Test-Path  "${filePath}${currentDate}$_.txt"
}
```

Comment: Thanks this did work, although I didn't really mean to name my files that way. I've changed it now to show what I'm really checking for.

Comment: Thanks @BenH. I can't vote it seems but did accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in PowerShell.

```
$filePath = "C:\Desktop\test\$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd"))"

foreach ( $n in 1..4 ) {
    Test-Path $($filePath +"file$n.txt")
}
```

Comment: All of the `$item`s in your loop will return `$True` with `Test-Path` because `Get-ChildItem` will only get the files that exist.

Comment: @Benh Good point, silly logic mistake trying to take a short cut.